# How to login to a Docker Registry that has an HTTP prefix set?

Tags: docker, docker-registry

I have setup my own Docker Registry, but I did not want it on the root URL so when I created the service I used the `REGISTRY_HTTP_PREFIX` environment variable and set it to `/registry/`, thus the URL to the registry is `https://tools.example.com/registry`. This is being proxied by Nginx which has Basic Auth setup on it.

I tested access to the registry using a Browser and I was able to get it to show that there are no repositories by going to `http://tools.example.com/registry/v2/_catalog`:

[image]

This led me to think that it was workoing. However when I try to login to the registry using the Docker command line, I get the Basic Auth challenge but then it fails to login because the URL is incorrect, e.g.

```
docker login -u russells -p xxxxxxxx https://tools.example.com/registry/
Error response from daemon: login attempt to https://tools.example.com/v2/ failed with status: 404 Not Found
```

As can be seen from the error, the prefix is not being added properly. SO how can I login to the registry so I can push images. Is there an environment variable or something that I am missing to make the `docker login` work properly?

**Update - 2017-08-12 2253 BST**

I Have been playing around with the configuration a bit, but I am still not getting very far.

As requested here are my configuration files.

*nginx.conf*

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    upstream docker-registry {
        server registry:5000;
    }

    map $upstream_http_docker_distribution_api_version $docker_distribution_api_version {
        '' 'registry/2.0';
    }

    server {
        listen 15000;
        server_name tools.example.com;

        # disable any limits to avoid HTTP 413 for large image uploads
        client_max_body_size 0;

        # required to avoid HTTP 411
        chunked_transfer_encoding on;

        location /registry/ {

            # Do not allow connections from docker 1.5. and earlier
            # docker pre-1.6.0 did not properly set the user agent on ping, catch "Go *" user agents
            if ($http_user_agent ~ "^(docker\/1\.(3|4|5(?!\.[0-9]-dev))|Go ).*$") {
                return 404;
            }

            auth_basic "Docker Registry";
            auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;

            add_header 'Docker-Distribution-Api-Version' $docker_distribution_api_version always;

            proxy_pass                      http://docker-registry/registry/;
            proxy_set_header    Host        $http_host;
            proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP   $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_read_timeout              900;

        }
    }
}
```

My Docker Registry service is deployed as `registry` and is running on the default port of 5000. Looking at this now I think I have got things confused. I do not need the registry to answer on the prefix itself, just Nginx.

For example if I leave the location set to `/` then I can login, but if I change this to `/registry/` then I am not able to. I am beginning to think that the two are conflicting each other.

*Registry*

I have not set a configuration for the Registry other than the one environment variable - `REGISTRY_HTTP_PREFIX`, which maybe surplus to requirements in this setup.

**Update - 2017-08-15 1100 BST**

In order to test the `prefix` for the registry I created a registry container with the following configuration file:

```
version: 0.1
auth:
  htpasswd:
    realm: Docker Registry
    path: /auth/etc/htpasswd
storage:
  filesystem:
    rootdirectory: /var/lib/registry
    maxthreads: 100
http:
  addr: 0.0.0.0:5000
  prefix: /registry/
  tls:
    certificate: /auth/ssl/certs/registry.cert
    key: /auth/ssl/private/registry.key
```

As this is using self signed certificates I updated my Docker engine by placing the certificate in `/etc/docker/certs.d/host-lin-01:5000`.

I then created the container with the following command:

`docker run -it --rm -p 5000:5000 --name registry_test -v ~/workspaces/docker/registry/etc/registry.yml:/etc/docker/registry/config.yml -v ~/workspaces/docker/registry:/auth registry:2`

If I try and login to the registry with the command:

`docker login -u russells -p xxxxxx https://host-lin-01:5000/registry`

I get the following error:

`Error response from daemon: login attempt to https://host-lin-01:5000/v2/ failed with status: 404 Not Found`

Now if I remove the `perfix: /registry/` line from the registry yaml file and restart the container and then login all is well:

```
docker login -u russells -p xxxxxx https://turtle-host-03:5000/
Login Succeeded
```

What is strange, however, is that the login works for *any* prefix I put on the end of the login URL, e.g.

```
docker login -u russells -p xxxxxx https://turtle-host-03:5000/registry/fred/34
Login Succeeded
```

I do not understand this. I must be misunderstanding what the `prefix` setting does.

Comment: Post your nginx config and the registry config you have used

Comment: @TarunLalwani Added configuration as requested.

Answer (score 0):

You issue is the application of your Basic Auth. So you have Nginx with Basic Auth which is backed by a plain registry.

You are able to authenticate urls and see the _catalog blank json, and that make you feel it is working. But technically what is happening is that your Nginx is asking for username/password, which gets it and then passes is on to you docker registry. Which in turn has no authentication.

Now when you use `docker login` you are expecting a authenticated registry but you have a authenticated nginx and non-authenticated registry. So you need to ditch the below lines of code from your nginx config

```
auth_basic "Docker Registry";
auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
```

Also when launching your registry you need to define the below environment variables

```
  REGISTRY_AUTH: htpasswd
  REGISTRY_AUTH_HTPASSWD_PATH: /auth/htpasswd
  REGISTRY_AUTH_HTPASSWD_REALM: Registry Realm
```

Make sure you map `/auth/htpasswd` from your host to the registry container.  Do this and the setup should work. Also make sure to setup the server certificates in your docker client system

**Optional Changes**

Next part of this answer is optional as such. Since you are using Nginx and Registry both. I would suggest you ditch the `REGISTRY_HTTP_PREFIX` from your registry and change the `proxy_pass` to

```
proxy_pass http://docker-registry/;
```

Comment: Thank you for this, it has given me an idea to remove Nginx from the equation :-). However I am slightly confused with your suggestion. When I attempt to login with the HTTP prefix of `/registry` the `login` command comes back with `Error response from daemon: login attempt to https://tools.example.com/v2/ failed with status: 404 Not Found`, where the prefix is _not_ in the response so how would it know where to push images. I have another setup which works well as the registry is set to root. I will give this a go in the morning though, thanks again.

Comment: @RussellSeymour, try it and if it doesn't work let me know

Comment: Unfortunately I get the same issue :-(. I stripped out Nginx completely and just went with the Registry and specified the Env vars as you suggested, but I still get a 404 error on the command line when I try to login.

Comment: @RussellSeymour, did you setup the SSL certificates for the registry or not and also did you setup insecure registry settings on docker client to login on http regitsry?

Comment: I am now taking this back to basics and building a simple docker registry with self signed certificates and trying to get it work like that. At the moment I am having problems with the initial login with an EOF error being thrown but I am sure that is just a configuration issue. I will update when I have something I can play with. Thanks for you help so far.

Comment: I have updated my original post with the testing i have done. Things have moved on but I am unlcear as to what is happening.